# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_label'

Tags: python, matplotlib, ggplot2, plot, attributeerror

I'm trying basic plot with two y-axis and one x-axis. To obtain the legend information for different curve I'm getting AttributeError.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2.0*np.pi, 101)
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.sinh(x)

# separate the figure object and axes object from the plotting object
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# Duplicate the axes with a differebt y axis and the same x axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # ax2 and ax1 will have common x axis and different y axis

# plot the curves on axes 1, and 2 and get the curve hadles
curve1 = ax1.plot(x, y, label="sin", color='r')
curve2 = ax2.plot(x, z, label="sinh", color='b')

# Make a curves list to access the parameters in the curves
curves = [curve1, curve2]

# Add legend via axes1 or axex 2 object.
# ax1.legend() will not display the legend of ax2
# ax2.legend() will not display the legend of ax1

ax1.legend(curves, [curve.get_label() for curve in curves])
#ax2.legend(curves, [curve.get_label() for curve in curves]) also valid

# Global figure properties
plt.title("Plot of sine and hyperbolic sine")
plt.show()
```

I'm getting Error on below line:

```
ax1.legend(curves, [curve.get_label() for curve in curves])
```

Please let me know if anyone know why its happening.

Comment: Check the docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html `plot` returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2.0*np.pi, 101)
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.sinh(x)

# separate the figure object and axes object from the plotting object
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# Duplicate the axes with a differebt y axis and the same x axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # ax2 and ax1 will have common x axis and different y axis

# plot the curves on axes 1, and 2 and get the curve hadles
curve1 = ax1.plot(x, y, label="sin", color='r')
curve2 = ax2.plot(x, z, label="sinh", color='b')

# Make a curves list to access the parameters in the curves
curves = curve1 + curve2

# Add legend via axes1 or axex 2 object.
# ax1.legend() will not display the legend of ax2
# ax2.legend() will not display the legend of ax1
labs = [curve.get_label() for curve in curves]
ax1.legend(curves, labs, loc=0)

#ax1.legend(curves, [curve.get_label() for curve in curves])
#ax2.legend(curves, [curve.get_label() for curve in curves]) also valid

# Global figure properties
plt.title("Plot of sine and hyperbolic sine")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Consider posting the code with the changes all together

Answer (score -1):

if you read the [pyplot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), you can see that the plot function returns a list, which clearly does not have a method `get_label()`.

What you want is probably what is described in [matplotlib's legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), which is automatic detection of your plot's labels.
This means that you do not have to store your line results, and your legend calls goes from

```py
ax1.legend(curves, [curve.get_label() for curve in curves])
```

to simply

```py
ax1.legend()
```

In my opinion reading the documentation not only solves your problem in most cases, but gives you a very important ability in the world of programming, which is to be able to solve the problems on your own (as well as reading documentations).

Cheers